# Capistrano multistage - not creating dev/prod symlinks (only 'current')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano, multistage

I've set this up before but can't get it to work now. I want a development and production site. When I do cap deploy it'll setup a "current" symlink (not sure how I did that since for a long time it wouldn't even do that). But how do I get it to deploy and setup the necessary symlink for dev/prod?

My deploy.rb file:

```
#require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require 'capistrano_colors'

set :stages, %w(development production)
set :default_stage, 'development'

set :application, "myapp"
set :repository,  "***"

# Target directory on the server
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"

set :scm, :git
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :user, '***'
set :use_sudo, false

role :web, "68.225.130.30"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "68.225.130.30"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "68.225.130.30", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

# List of symlinks to be generated. Keys are subdirectories of release_path.
SYMLINKS = { :config => ['database.yml'],
             :public => ['system'] }

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
    # Not working =/
    #run "touch /var/www/#{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  desc "Set up application symlinks."
  task :app_symlinks do
    SYMLINKS.keys.each do |key|
      dir = key.to_s
      SYMLINKS[key].each do |path|
        run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/#{dir}/#{path} #{release_path}/#{dir}/#{path}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

my deploy/development.rb file:

```
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"
set :branch, "master"
unset :rails_env
set :rails_env, "development"
```

UPDATE/ANSWER:

Issue was with the current_path variable. Weird since I've tried using

set :current_path, "development"

and

set :current_path, "#{application}/development"

and it didn't work. Looks like I have to set the entire path, which seems weird since I've used the latter before.

```
set :current_path, "/var/www/#{application}/development"
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

:current_path is set by capistrano based on the :deploy_to path + the :application name.  You can only use :current_path within your namespaced tasks.

In other words, it's a convenience  variable used for creating symlinks, restarting servers, and other tasks.